# How can I enter a number and put it into the end of a character array? (C)

Tags: arrays, c

When the user enters a number, like 1101, I would like it to story it in a 16-bit binary character array like this:

Enter Number:

1101

16 bit Binary character array: {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1}

Right now I have this code that does this but it stores the number starting on the left, so the result is {1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}:

```
int main(void){
    int operand1[16] = {0};// array of ints
    char c;
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'){ //main loop
    
        if (c == '1'){ //1's
            operand1[index]++;
            index++;
        }
        else if (c == '0'){ //0's 
            index++;
        }
    }
    
    
    for(i = 0; i<16; i++){
        printf("%d", operand1[i]);
    }
    
return 0;
}
```

How can we flip this so that the number enters the back of the array in the correct order?

Any help would be appreciated

Edit: We can start at the back of the array and index there, however it will enter the number into the array backwards. This is the issue.

Comment: Instead of `index++`, have you considered writing code that involves `index--`?

Comment: @mkrieger1, if we start with index = 15 and increment down, we are left with something like {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1}. The leading zeros are there but the entered number will be backwards.

Comment: You can't do it character by character directly into the final buffer because you don't know how many characters the user will enter (unless it's always 4). So need to read the whole string into a temporary buffer first and then construct the final buffer from that.

Answer (score 1):

You could fill `operand1[]` from the end and count the length of the input while reading.
Then it's just a matter of reversing the string starting from the last number written, which in pseudocode is `sizeof(operand1) - input_length`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE_OF(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))

void reverse(int *s, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++){
        int tmp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-i-1];
        s[n-i-1] = tmp;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int operand1[16] = {0};// array of ints
    char c;
    int i = SIZE_OF(operand1) - 1;

    while (i >= 0 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'){ //main loop
    
        if (c == '1'){ //1's
            operand1[i]++;
            i--;
        }
        else if (c == '0'){ //0's 
            i--;
        }
    }
    
    i++;
    reverse(&operand1[i], SIZE_OF(operand1) - i);
    
    
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE_OF(operand1); i++){
        printf("%d", operand1[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/IgkssV6rG

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of the solutions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void){
    int operand1[16] = {0};// array of ints
    char c;
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0;

    int tempOperand[16] = {0};
    int startIndex = 0;
    int inputSize = 0;    

    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'){ //main loop 

        if (c == '1'){ //1's
            operand1[index]++;
            tempOperand[index]++;           
            index++;                        
        }
        else if (c == '0'){ //0's 
            index++;
        }
    }

    inputSize = index;  

    startIndex = 16 - inputSize;
    printf("Input size %d\n", inputSize); 
    printf("Start index: %d\n", startIndex);

    for(i = 0; i<16; i++){
        operand1[i] = 0;
    }

    for (i = startIndex; i < 16; ++i){
        operand1[i] = tempOperand[i-startIndex];
    }    

    for(i = 0; i<16; i++){
        printf("%d", operand1[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```